# Omniauth and google oauth2 error without Devise - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

**EDIT: I HAVE FOLLOWED THE ANSWER BELOW AND REFRESHED POST BECAUSE I WAS STUCK ELSEWHERE, THE GIVEN ANSWER BELOW IS CORRECT.**

Hey guys so i am trying to implement social authentications but i am stuck.

I've setup correctly the callback url both in my routes and google console and i've verified it by displaying the auth_hash in browser.

my **session_controller.rb**

```
def google_oauth2
auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']

@user = User.find_by_provider_and_uid(auth_hash["provider"], auth_hash["uid"])
if @user
  log_in @user
  flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
else
  @user = User.new(
    uid: auth_hash['uid'],
    provider: auth_hash['provider'],
    name: auth_hash['info']['name'],
    email: auth_hash['info']['email'],
    image_url: auth_hash['info']['image'],
    oauth_token: auth_hash['credentials']['token'],
    oauth_refresh_token: auth_hash['credentials']['refresh_token'],
    oauth_expires_at: auth_hash['credentials']['expires_at']
  )
  if @user.save
    log_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Hello, #{@user.name}! An account has been created for you!"
  else
    flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
  end
end
redirect_to root_path
```

end

**User.model**

```
validates :name,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 50 }



  validates :email,
            presence: true,
            length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive:false }

  has_secure_password
  validates :password,
            presence:true,
            length: { minimum: 8 },
            allow_nil: true
```

And this is the error in console

```
    Started GET "/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=00407988327c46ec93248da4dadba18c56efc88ef44c36b0&code=4/l666HRBZExC2XR93sI4VP7pWIYAkNySwD75sHtSOb_o" for ::1 at 2015-08-07 02:43:34 +0300
I, [2015-08-07T02:43:34.321568 #6869]  INFO -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by SessionsController#google_oauth2 as HTML
  Parameters: {"state"=>"00407988327c46ec93248da4dadba18c56efc88ef44c36b0", "code"=>"4/l666HRBZExC2XR93sI4VP7pWIYAkNySwD75sHtSOb_o", "provider"=>"google_oauth2"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = ? AND "users"."uid" = ? LIMIT 1  [["provider", "google_oauth2"], ["uid", "118084345864130537689"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('testemail@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 20ms (ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

The problem is that the error in my session controller fires each time,and no user is created

```
"There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
```

Anyone who can collaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rescue is most likely caused not because of the `@user.save!`, but rather an error from `user.uid = auth_hash['uid']` because `user` is not set.

Simply remove `user.` from all names and it should work.

P.S.

1.You should never use rescue without specifying an error to rescue from(now it just skips every single error that might come up).

2. Assigning all parameters to variables is unnecessary. Use them directly
3. You should really refactor most of this code. Most of your controller code should go into the model.

My Version of your code would be something like this:

session_controller.rb

```
def google_oauth2
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    if User.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
     User.new(uid: auth_hash['uid'],
      provider: auth_hash['provider'],
      name: auth_hash['info']['name'],
      email: auth_hash['info']['email'],
      image_url: auth_hash['info']['image'])

      if @user.save!
       flash[:success] = "Welcome, #{@user.name}!You've signed up!"
      else
       flash[:warning] = "There was an error while trying to authenticate you..."
      end
    end
    redirect_to root_path
end
```

user.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth_hash)
      find_by(uid: auth_hash['uid'], provider: auth_hash['provider'])
end
```

But it would be even better if you put all of the code for creating a user in the model as well.

Comment: hello, thank you for the help, your advice helped me a lot, rescue masked a lot of errors! but it seems that something with my validations gives me that error. (i have updated the entire post), do you know why? i think it has something to do with the password validation.

Comment: i've found that since i don't use devise i had to create random password just to input into the fields even though it won't be used by users as its social logins. So saving a random password to password and password_confirmation fields did the trick. thanks again

Comment: If you only use social network login, why would you want a password in the first place? Also, email validation might be tricky, because if I'm not mistaken, people can also NOT let you see their e-mail when they register for your app. In that case the login process for them will fail because the validation will fail.

Comment: Come to think of it, validation is useless in this case for any attribute because they are not user-controlled. i.e. that is not user's input but rather what is returned from the social network. I suggest to delete the validations unless user can change something after the initial login process.

Comment: actually its not useless for me at least, as i have normal registering function as well and since everything lives inside the same User model,i think what i did is necessary. But as for the email, is there a work around?

Comment: Well, if you really need to have a valid e-mail for each user you can redirect after facebook login to a page, where the user must enter his e-mail. If having a valid e-mail is optional, then you could just provide a random e-mail if a user has not agreed to share his. 

Something like `...email: auth_hash['info']['email'] || "email@email.com",`

Comment: Also, if the user is logged-in via social network you could use a conditional validation to check if a user even needs a password. This way you might save some memory in the long-term.